# CiviCRM 5.x is storing lot of empty records while sign petition

Tags: drupal, civipetiton

I am using Drupal 7 with CiviCRM 5.x version and I am not sure why but civicrm is storing lots of empty records(means no email, name etc) it just creates user record.

[image]

All these empty details records are created from petition page.

Is anyone faced same king of issue? any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same pb of "blank" contacts when a petition is signed (Form/Profile hosted on an other website).
Drupal / civicrm V4.7.31

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: no and I can't reproduce this... mais be somthing with the browser use by le contact on the website side :-(